# Understanding Natural log in the given expression

Tags: calculus, integration, random-variables, logarithms

In my work, I came across the following expression:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\text{exp}\left[-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\right]$---(1)

Taking natural log of eq. (1)

$-\text{ln}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}$---(2)

I understood that natural log and exponential will cancel each other, my query is that I am not getting how in eq. (2) $-\text{ln}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}$ is coming.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: $\log(1/x)=-\log(x)$

Comment: And also $\log(AB) = \log(A) + \log(B)$.

Comment: @ Claude, @ Annie....Thank u so much for your response